# separating factor and character columns in r data frame using multiple condition

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I would like to separate only two types of a column of the data frame (factors and characters) and the following codes results in an error. I wonder what is the correct way to carry out this task.

```
install.packages("dslabs")
library(dslabs)
data(murders)

names(murders)[sapply(murders, (is.factor | is.character))]
```

I can use the following code to combine the two, but I wonder what will be the correct format in case I want to use multiple conditions as the code above.

```
c(names(murders)[sapply(murders, is.factor)],names(murders)[sapply(murders, is.character)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may need a lambda function

```
names(murders)[sapply(murders, function(x) 
      is.factor(x) | is.character(x))]
```

Or another option is to get the `class` and use `%in%`

```
names(murders)[sapply(murders, class) %in% c("factor", "character")]
```

Or with `Filter`

```
names(Filter(function(x) is.factor(x)|is.character(x), murders))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
murders %>%
    select(where(~ is.factor(.x)|is.character(.x))) %>%
    names
```